# DuplicateKeyException in mongodb and spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot and MongoDB and I am able to store a document in MongoDB successfully. When I was trying to insert a second document, it is showing `duplicatekeyexception`. The total message of exception is as follows:

> com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000
>   and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error collection:
>   Football_Admin.SignUp index: *id* dup key: { : 0 }'

The code is as follows:

SignUpRepository.java

```
package com.admin.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.admin.Model.SignUp;

@Repository
public interface SignUpRepository extends MongoRepository<SignUp,String>{

}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/SignIn_Up")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    SignUpRepository repository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/addadmin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addAdmin(@ModelAttribute("SignUp") SignUp sign) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,InvalidKeySpecException {
        String  originalPassword = sign.getPassword();
        String generatedSecuredPasswordHash = generateStorngPasswordHash(originalPassword);
        String email = sign.getEmail();
        String fullname = sign.getFullName();
        try {
        sign.setEmail(email);
        sign.setFullName(fullname);
        sign.setPassword(generatedSecuredPasswordHash);
        repository.save(sign);
        }
        catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(generatedSecuredPasswordHash);
        System.out.println("Email name is:"+sign.getEmail());
        System.out.println("Full Name is:"+sign.getFullName());
        System.out.println("Password is:"+sign.getPassword());
        return "welcome";
    }
```

Entity

```
package com.admin.Model;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="SignUp")
public class SignUp {
@Id
private int id;
private String fullName;
private String email;
private String password;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}
public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String toString() {
    return id+""+fullName+""+password;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


}
```

Comment: What's your entity look like?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Added Entity. Refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDb driver don't know how to create a unique Id of type `int` when inserting so you received unique index exception

So either you manually create and maintain your index (quite hard) or change your id field type to `ObjectId`

Comment: Thank You . Just changed the data type to String and its working perfectly.

Comment: If possible is there any resource that can be useful on how to manually create and maintain your index??

Answer (score 0):

repository.save(sign);
this causes error by means of creating new document which makes duplicate key error
//.save not works for update that as expected

```
 private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public UserService(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }
```

use for updating
also check for proper import

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public UserService(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    public void followUser(String userName, String followUserName) {
        User user = userRepository.findByName(userName);
        User followUser = userRepository.findByName(followUserName);
        
        if (user != null && followUser != null) {
            // Update the following list of the current user
            if (!user.getFollowing().contains(followUser.getId())) {
                user.getFollowing().add(followUser.getId());
                
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(user.getId())),
                        new Update().addToSet("following", followUser.getId()), User.class);
            }

            if (!followUser.getFollowers().contains(user.getId())) {
                followUser.getFollowers().add(user.getId());
                mongoTemplate.updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(followUser.getId())),
                        new Update().addToSet("followers", user.getId()), User.class);
            }
        } else {
            throw new UserNotExists("User or follow user not found.");//custom exception
        }
    }
}
```